# Limiting laravel pagination center to 3

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm having trouble in my pagination because i have to many data in my database. I want to limit or reduce the display in pagination center for it didn't fit in mobile sizes. The image below display 5 pagination in center. i want to make it 3. I am using laravel 6 ang latest bootstrap.

[image]

here is my code

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i already added my code

Comment: Why are you rendering the pager manually?

Comment: its from the default pagination of the laravel. i just customize it a little

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results):

> You may control how many additional links are displayed on each side of the paginator's URL "window". By default, three links are displayed on each side of the primary paginator links. However, you may control this number using the `onEachSide` method:

```
{{ $users->onEachSide(5)->links() }}
```

---

So in your case, you need `onEachSide(1)` to get three links.

Comment: i already use onEachSide(1) but it still shows 5 page in the middle

Answer (score 0):

- Try this in your query builder page for your table

  Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);

Answer (score 0):

Based upon @Jerodev, you are rendering the pager manually on your blade view, which seems unnecessary.

For debugging process, the only thing I can think of is try to delete or modify  your `@if` block one by one to see how it changes the view of pagination.

Based on the logic of your code, I believe the issue is 
[image]

it creates `-2` and `+2` range of your current page, which it's 5, so you just want to change it to `-1` and `+1` so to be 3.

It seems like you did not understand the code you were writing so I have to suspect that you pasted that from somewhere else. If this is the case, I suggest you always want to modify something to see how it works if the code is from online source.

Comment: yeah i just found it out last time when i was able to fix it. thanks for the answer.